# How can I tell if someone joins my server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How can I tell if someone joins my Minecraft PE server? I just got my sever set up so I'm learning everything.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a player joins, a message will display, to inform you.

> "Username joined the game"